# Memory utilization in %(Percentage) in Sun Solaris?

Tags: bash, awk, solaris, memory

I would like to get the memory utilization in sun solaris system in % percentage format.

```
vmstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk 'a=`/usr/sbin/prtconf|fgrep Memory|awk '{print $3*1024}'{ print 100-($5/$a)*100}'
```

Getting below error:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

Also, please suggest if any alternative possible for this query?

Comment: does the awk command you tried really has ``a=`/usr/sbin/prtconf|fgrep Memory|awk`` or is it a copy-paste error?

Comment: That error message is because you used the default awk on Solaris, `/usr/bin/awk` aka old, broken awk. Never use that awk - on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or xpg6) as that's the closest to POSIX compliance on Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Solaris `awk` (which would not have the `-v` switch or allow setting variables), and using your original query to start with, you can do:

Percentage of free memory:

```
a=$(/usr/sbin/prtconf | /usr/bin/awk '/Memory/ {print $3*1024}'); vmstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk "{print (\$5/$a)*100}"
```

Percentage of used memory:

```
a=$(/usr/sbin/prtconf | /usr/bin/awk '/Memory/ {print $3*1024}'); vmstat 1 1 | tail -1 | awk "{print 100-(\$5/$a)*100}"
```

Assign the variable in shell first, then execute the `vmstat` query using shell variable substitution.  This requires using the double quotes in the `awk` and making sure to escape the `awk` variable.  You also do not need to use `fgrep` and `awk` together, `awk` can do both.

Tested on my Opensolaris I have available, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ::memstat | mdb -k
```

Will produce percent usage of memory by kernel, zfs, users and free.

You need to be root.